# how much money you spend each month?

Tags: pakistani-citizens

As i dependent on my father so my source of income is my family and spend 20,000 PKR each month in my living as i already submitted my university fee of full semester. so my question is that what should i mention in regarding to above question they asked 
Do you have regular source of income or savings?
how much money you spend each month?

Answer (score 0):

You should say "No" to regular source of income or savings, since you are a dependent.

Comment: but if i click option i have regular source of income from my family as my family supports me in my livings? would it be right or not?

Comment: Income is money you earn, not money given to you. If you don't have a job, you don't have income - it is that simple :-)

Comment: oh i see, thank you very much burhan khalid for clarfication

Comment: but there is no option in which tell them i dependent on my father. instead they asked does anyone relay on me? so, if i attached my father bank statement it makes sense that i depend on him?